# Python socket.recv() hangs after connection drop

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, recv, python-sockets

I have implemented a server in Python 3.8.6 using the socket library (running on a Raspberry Pi 4 w/ 8G RAM & Raspberry Pi OS: Buster) which, by design, only handles a single connection at a time. When a connection is gained, the server spawns two threads, one for sending data, and one for receiving it. When the connection is lost (in theory, it will never be intentionally closed), these threads are terminated and a new thread is spawned to accept a new connection. The problem is, the receiving thread never actually terminates, instead getting stuck infinitely on `socket.recv()`. This persists even after calling `socket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR)` and `socket.close()`. The code is essentially as follows (I've paired it down to only the pertinent bits and left the heartbeat management code, as I've found this is the only way I can consistently tell that the connection has dropped, as the errors that are supposed to be thrown don't always):

```
import dataclasses
import logging
import pickle
import queue
import socket
import threading
import time
import traceback



log = logging.getLogger()


class Server(threading.Thread):
    @dataclasses.dataclass
    class Heartbeat:
        failures: int = 0
        reciprocate: bool = True
        time: float = 0

    __CLIENT_IP = '10.1.1.58'
    __EOF = "\r\nEOF\r\n".encode()
    __PORT = 33368

    def __init__(self, kill_flag:threading.Event) -> None:
        self.__kill_flag: threading.Event = kill_flag
        self.__server = socket.create_server(("", self.__PORT), backlog=0, reuse_port=True)
        self.__server.settimeout(5)
        self.__client = None
        self.__queue_out = queue.Queue(-1)
        self.__queue_in = queue.Queue(-1)
        self._connected = False
        self.__connecting_lock = threading.Lock()
        self.__receive_thread = None
        self.__transmit_thread = None
        threading.Thread(target=self.__connect).start()

    def __connect(self) -> None:
        with self.__connecting_lock:
            if self._connected:
                return
            addr = ("", 0)
            if self.__client:
                try:
                    self.__client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
                except OSError:
                    pass
                finally:
                    self.__client.close()
            self.__client = None
            while (self.__receive_thread and self.__receive_thread.is_alive()) or (self.__transmit_thread and self.__transmit_thread.is_alive()):
                    log.debug("connected: %s, recv alive: %s, trans alive: %s", self._connected, self.__receive_thread.is_alive(), self.__transmit_thread.is_alive())
                    time.sleep(1)
            log.info("Waiting for connection...")
            while addr[0] != self.__CLIENT_IP and not self.__kill_flag.is_set():
                try:
                    self.__client, addr = self.__server.accept()
                    if addr[0] != self.__CLIENT_IP:
                        self.__client.close()
                        log.warning("Connection from %s:%s - Rejected", addr[0], addr[1])
                        time.sleep(1)
                except socket.timeout:
                    continue
            if self.__kill_flag.is_set():
                self.__del__()
            else:
                log.info("Connection from %s:%s - Accepted", addr[0], addr[1])
                self.heartbeat = self.Heartbeat()
                self._connected = True
                self.__receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__receive)
                self.__transmit_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.__transmit)
                self.__queue_in.queue.clear()
                self.__receive_thread.start()
                self.__transmit_thread.start()

    def get_package(self) -> tuple:
        return self.__queue_out.get(True)

    def queue_message(self, content:tuple = ()) -> None:
        self.__queue_in.put_nowait(content)

    def __receive(self) -> None:
        buffer = bytearray()
        while self._connected and not self.__kill_flag.is_set():
            try:
                if self.__EOF in buffer:
                    payload = pickle.loads(buffer.split(self.__EOF, maxsplit=1)[0])
                    self.__queue_out.put_nowait(payload)
                    buffer = bytearray(self.__EOF.join(buffer.split(self.__EOF)[1:]))
                else:
                    try:
                        log.debug("looping into recv")
                        data = self.__client.recv(1024)
                        log.debug("looping past recv")
                        if len(data) == 0:
                            raise ConnectionResetError
                        else:
                            buffer += data
                    except OSError as error:
                        log.error(f"Receive error: {error}")
                        if self._connected:
                            self._connected = False
                            threading.Thread(target=self.__connect).start()
                    except AttributeError:
                        break
            except socket.timeout:
                continue
            except Exception as error:
                log.error(f"Receive error: {error}")
                traceback.print_tb(error.__traceback__)
                if self._connected:
                    self._connected = False
                    threading.Thread(target=self.__connect).start()

    def __transmit(self) -> None:
        while self._connected and not self.__kill_flag.is_set():
            try:
                payload = self.__queue_in.get(True, 5)
            except queue.Empty:
                if self.heartbeat.reciprocate:
                    payload = (time.time(),)
                    self.heartbeat.reciprocate = False
                elif time.time() - 7 >= self.heartbeat.time:
                    self.heartbeat.failures += 1
                    log.debug("Heartbeat failure")
                    if self.heartbeat.failures >= 3:
                        log.warning("Lost connection to client: No heartbeat detected")
                        if self._connected:
                            self._connected = False
                            threading.Thread(target=self.__connect).start()
                    self.heartbeat.reciprocate = True
                    continue
                else:
                    continue
            self.heartbeat.time = time.time()
            try:
                self.__client.sendall(pickle.dumps(payload))
                log.debug("Package sent: %s", payload)
            except BrokenPipeError:
                log.warning("Lost connection to client: Broken pipe")
                self.__queue_in.put_nowait(payload)
                if self._connected:
                    self._connected = False
                    threading.Thread(target=self.__connect).start()
            except AttributeError:
                break

    def __del__(self) -> None:
        if self.__client:
            self.__client.close()
        self.__server.close()
```

After the connection drops, the `__receive` method/thread hangs specifically on this line: `data = self.__client.recv(1024)`.

Perhaps the strangest part is that the client, whose `__transmit` and `__receive` methods are virtually identical, does not have this problem.

Any insight anyone can offer into as why this is happening, and how to remedy it, would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: If you call `socket.close()` on the client, `socket.recv()` on the server should return `0`. I'm not sure why that's not working for you.

Comment: Can you do a packet capture and check that the RPi is sending a `FIN` segment when the client calls `socket.close()`?

Comment: @Barmar In most failure cases, such as those I'm testing, no further network communications will be possible. Essentially, the only time the client is going to drop the connection is in the event of a power or network disruption. My system needs to be resilient to this, so I've been testing by purposely disconnecting the client from the network and watching how it all fails. The client cleans up and tries to reconnect nicely, the sever gets hung.

Comment: But the question says: "This persists even after calling socket.shutdown(SHUT_RDWR) and socket.close()." I thought you meant that the client was doing this.

Comment: The client has to actively close the connection for the server to detect it, unless you enable keepalives.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, sorry for the ambiguity. No, the server is calling this on it's own socket. More on the connection than the socket itself, where `self.__client, addr = self.__server.accept()` and what is called is `self.__client.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` followed by `self.__client.close()`. Similarly, the client makes the same call (assuming it's still powered) but won't be able to transmit that over the network.

Comment: If the server closes the client socket itself, I think `recv()` should raise an exception. I'm not sure what happens if you close in one thread while another thread is blocked in recv, though, but it seems like it should also raise an exception.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I thought as well, but it hasn't been. I even have `self.__server.settimeout(5)` set, which I thought would raise a timeout on `recv()` as well, but it hasn't been. Any chance you know of another way to interrupt `recv()`? `shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)` was the only thing I could find that that's not working :/ You mentioned keepalives, do you think that's a solution here?